# sed wrong filename recognized

Tags: bash, variables, sed, sh

Why sed interprets the filename given in the variable wrong? (/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf interpreted as esql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf)

script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
...
echo "$psql_config_file"
${ssh_login} sudo -Hiu postgres sed -i 's/[#]*wal_level\ =.*#/wal_level\ =\ archive\ #/g' "$psql_config_file"
```

output:

```
+ echo $'/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf\r'
/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf
+ ssh -t user@192.168.42.133 sudo -Hiu postgres sed -i 's/[#]*wal_level\=.*#/wal_level\ =\ archive\ #/g' $'/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf\r'
: No such file or directoryesql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf
```

Comment: Because it has an extra `\r` (aka `^M`, aka `CR`) at the end. Probably because somewhere you have a file with DOS line endings and are using that to set the variable containing the file name.

Comment: The `$'\r'` is right there in the `set -x` log. See the **very first thing** in the "before asking about problematic code"  section at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info